# Exception when upgrading the spring web jar from 5.1.3 to Spring web 5.1.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, content-type, nosuchmethoderror

Need to upgrade the version of spring web from 5.1.3 to any higher version. Tried upgrading latest version also but still same exception.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.equalsTypeAndSubtype(Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)Z

All the mockmvc test are failling.
Content type not set
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set

Comment: You cannot just upgrade `spring-web` you need to upgade all spring dependencies.

Comment: I have many spring dependencies in the project .So if I update spring-boot-starter ,will it update all the dependencies?

Comment: Yes but then again you have to update all starters to the same version. Never mix different versions of a framework, that will inevitably come back to bite you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried rebuilding the project from within the IDE as well as via the build tool? Sometimes things get cached (incorrectly) and don't update, then you get this error?

Comment: This is hardly an answer, rather a comment.